# Total product count display wrong in toolbar

Tags: magento2, product-collection, toolbar

```
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_productCollection->clear()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('author', array('eq' => 'Author-1'))
        ->load();
$this->setCollection($_productCollection);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a different approach to leverage native Magento functionality with custom filterable attributes.

After double-checking the attribute settings are compatible, for example that the `author` attribute's setting is configured to enable it as a `filterable` attribute, then change the way that you are handling the product listing so that native Magento functionality will handle proper product collection filtering when filtered by `author`.  If you are attempting to filter per a specific author, you can do rewrites, or create custom pages that pre-apply the filter by simple url parameters.

Review attribute creation and usage:

http://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/stores/attribute-product-create.html

---

**Side note:** You are obtaining a loaded product collection from a block, then setting it within `$this`.  I'm certain that there are different code approaches that must be taken before and after the collection has been loaded.  I am unsure if a loaded collection can simply be cleared, then work properly with `addAttributeToFilter(...)` method.  I would think that even if it does work, you would still want to `$block->setLoadedProductCollection($_productCollection);`, instead.